# Rails - view: Ruby code in link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, embedded-ruby

I'd like to have embededd ruby code as my link name. Right now I tried to implement it like this:

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= link_to '<%= user.familyname %>, <%= user.forename %> ', user %> </li>
<% end %>
```

But it's not working, Rails gives me a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'
...);@output_buffer.safe_concat('\', user %> </li>
...                               ^
```

What do I need to change in the syntax, so this Link will work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can not do <%= %> inside an <%= %>. you can try something like this:

```
    <% @users.each do |employee| %>
        <li><%= link_to "#{employee.familyname}, #{employee.forename}", employee %> </li>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple

```
<%= link_to [user.familyname, user.forename].join(','), user_path %>
```